Aura to LWC custom event, getParam('details') is null getParams('details') has data
I have an Aura component that I call a new LWC inside.
I set up a custom event on the LWC which is hit by the LWC and sends a response to the Aura. Here is the custom event on the LWC
//selectedAccount is defined by other methods
const accountSelectEvent = new CustomEvent('accountselect', {
    detail: { accountId: selectedAccount.Id },
    bubbles: true,
    composed: true
});        

Then in the calling Aura component I retrieve the event and try to parse it.
const dets = event.getParam('detail');
console.log('param', dets);
const eventDetails = event.getParams('detail');
console.log('params', eventDetails);
console.log('acct', eventDetails.accountId);

dets is null.
eventDetails is populated with my accountId.
Why am I having null in getParam but data in getParams? Shouldn't they both be populated?

event.getParam('detail'); should be event.getParam('accountId'). See Send Events to an Enclosing Aura Component. Edit: I should mention that getParams takes zero parameters, so you could write event.getParams('Monty Python') and you'd still get the contents of detail from LWC. JavaScript doesn't throw errors if there's too many parameters, or the wrong type, etc, because it is a loosely-typed language.

I tried to add getParam('accountId') and it still came back with no data. I did remove the parameter from getParams and it returned the values. That explains a bit more.
